# Using attr_encrypted to encrypt and store API token, but how to de-crypt in order to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, attr-encrypted

Building an app that pulls data from merchant's accounts on demand.

I've setup my model, installed the attr_encrypted gem, and everything is being stored properly as encrypted.

I've created a method that takes the token and sends it to the API, but I need to send the de-crypted version. The token is user specific so I don't know what it is..

How can I send the decrypted version of the token?

In my console I've tried..

```
x = Merchant.find(1)
x.encrypted_token
```

And that returns the encrypted version fine..

But if I try:

```
x.token
```

The console says ArgumentError: must specify a :key

Which I have stored as an environment variable..

So I guess I pass this along but how??

I have this in my model:

```
attr_encrypted :token, :key => ENV['token_key']
```

**Updates from comments**

this is what my db looks like:

```
"Merchant(merchant_identifier: string, name: string, encrypted_token: text, 
marketplace: string, password_digest: string, email: string)"
```

And I tried

```
    attr_encrypted :token, :key => 'token_key'
```

and it gave me a cipher error. I'm using figaro to store the environment variables.. seems like that's fine..

Keep it coming!!

What I am doing in irb is:

```
x = Merchant.find(2)
x.encrypted_token # yields "n4gZVJ8DKfp+p..."
```

but then if I follow this with

```
x.token
```

I get:

```
ArgumentError: must specify a :key
```

Comment: try this: `attr_encrypted :token, :key => 'YOUR_TOKEN_KEY'` maybe ENV['token_key'] is not defined

Comment: I have the same problem except I'm getting an `ArgumentError : must specify iv`, if I add `iv: "some_random_string"` to my model, then I get a `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:`

Comment: @GeoffreyH did have any luck solving this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need to add this to your :attr_encrypted:

```
attr_encrypted :encrypted_token, :key => Rails.env.test? ? 'ssn_secret' : ENV['SSN_SECRET']
```

There's also a conditional so that it won't break in production, when you put your keys in a file

Additionally:

> By default, the encrypted attribute name is encrypted_#{attribute} (e.g. attr_encrypted :email would create an attribute named encrypted_email). So, if you're storing the encrypted attribute in the database, you need to make sure the encrypted_#{attribute} field exists in your table

So do a `Merchant.inspect` or `Merchant.attribute_names` and see what kind of columns you have.

Comment: I updated the question, but I have 
attr_encrypted :token, :key => ENV['token_key']
In my model already, and I like the conditional, but when I do that I get a nil when I try x.encrypted_token in the console

Comment: It also might be  the column in your db , encrypted_token is a typre string. It should be :text

Comment: Tried that.. updated my question.. shoot!! what else??

Comment: If you're using the irb console, write down thr sequence of commands you enter that lead to getting the error

Comment: It was exactly my solution. Could not understand what that `key` thing was about, hidden inside a model but breaking my controller. You saved my day!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the key `ENV['token_key']` does NOT exist on the env. you are using?

Make sure it does exist and restart that environment and it should work.